# ¿Hay alguna forma de saltearse un captcha en una tarea programada?

Tags: html, python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Me ha dado la duda de que si en python con selenium se podria saltar o evitar, un captcha. Esos que validan si eres un robot o no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Antes me parecian tonto esas validaciones, ya siendo programador me resultan un inconveniente para realizar tareas programadas en sitios web.

He intentado algo con Pytesseract pero solo funciona con letras poco distersionadas dejando ese codigo un poco obsoleto debido a que la mayoria no era capaz de sacarlo correctamente.

Quisiera saber: ¿Como evitar estos captcha? ¿Hay alguna manera?

Comment: La idea de utilizar un Captcha en una pagina web, es precisamente que no se pueda automatizar con boots el uso de la misma. Cuando se usaban los captcha's de letras en imagenes si era posible. Hay algunas API's que podrian darte mas informacion [aqui](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17022/how-to-fill-captcha-using-test-automation). Otra opcion es que en entornos no productivos pidas al equipo de desarrollo que lo desactive. En este otro [enlace](http://scraping.pro/recaptcha-solve-selenium-python/) parece que lo consigue.

Comment: El Tesseact es muy bueno para captcha legible tipo timágenes con letras o números. Para el recaptcha necesitas solicitar un servicio tipo 2captcha.com, funciona enviando la clave publica de la pagina y tu sesión actual, ellos resuelven y mediante la api te devuelven el user token. El problema es que no es tan rapido puede demorar 15 seegundos en devolverte el token o 2 minutos y en ese tiempo puede expirar el token. Ademas que te cobran por el servicio.

Answer (score -2):

si es por js puede saltarse al deshabilitar js en el navegador, podrias tu copiar el codigo de la pagina web, correrlo sin el captcha y presionar enter.
aun si el boton html esta desabilitado con un "disabled" en su input, saltar eso es sumamente sencillo , ahora bien, en el lado del servidor no tanto pues , si este valida que no lo tienes pues sencillamente serás redirigido a la pagina que el servidor indique.
Una cosa es la validacion de parte del cliente (navegador) y otra la del servidor (y) bye

Comment: ah lo siento , pense que era cosa de navegadores, ando de idiota respondiendo sin ver la pregunta saludos, olvida lo que dije que aunque aplicable no responde con certeza a lo que preguntas

Answer (score -2):

```js
document.getElementById("recaptchamsg").setCustomValidity("");
document.getElementById("recaptchamsg").required = false;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero agrega una explicación de este código, revisa [answer], saludos.